# Is it possible to handle stream api call in Angular using ChatGPT API?

Tags: angular, http, chatgpt-api

[Link to stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-starter-project-daidh-pmhhyq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I made a mini app to work with chatgpt API(hide the api key). It works, however if the question/answer is too big, it takes much time or even exceeds the token limit of chatgpt. Is it possible to get the response in stream chunk by chunk? I can't figure out how to do it. In the provided code I tried it but only receive the first chunk. If there is any solution, i'll be glad to get help

Comment: unironically, ask chatgpt and it will tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get response in stream with `fetch` and [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream). Here is an example:

```js
chatStream(url, body, apikey) {
    return new Observable<string>(observer => {
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${apikey}`,
        },
      }).then(response => {
        const reader = response.body?.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        if (!response.ok) {
           // handle response error 
           observer.error();
        }

        function push() {
          return reader?.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            if (done) {
              observer.complete();
              return;
            }

            //parse text content from response
            const events = decoder.decode(value).split('\n\n');
            let content = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              const event = events[i];
              if (event === 'data: [DONE]') break;
              if (event && event.slice(0, 6) === 'data: ') {
                const data = JSON.parse(event.slice(6));
                content += data.choices[0].delta?.content || '';
              }
            }
            observer.next(content);
            push();
          });
        }

        push();
      }).catch((err: Error) => {
        // handle fetch error
        observer.error();
      });
    });
  }
```

And then subscribe like this

```js
let botMessage = ''

chatStream().subscribe({
    next: (text) => {
      botMessage += text
    },
    complete: () => {

    },
    error: () => {

    }
  });
```

Check out my complete application [here](https://github.com/ocherry341/custom-chatgpt). Each part can be found at [app/@core/http-api.service.ts](https://github.com/ocherry341/custom-chatgpt/blob/main/src/app/%40core/services/http-api.service.ts) and
[app/pages/chat/chat.component.ts](https://github.com/ocherry341/custom-chatgpt/blob/main/src/app/pages/chat/chat.component.ts).

If you found this helpful, I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me a star.